# iOS: How can I get JSON data with \" \ character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have JSON data in the following format:

```
{ "Data": "{ \"data\": { \"current_condition\": [ {\"cloudcover\": \"0\", \"humidity\": \"33\", \"observation_time\": \"07:40 AM\", \"precipMM\": \"0.0\", \"pressure\": \"1008\", \"temp_C\": \"29\", \"temp_F\": \"84\", \"visibility\": \"10\" } ] }}" }
```

I can get "Data" with

```
NSError *err=nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://something.smthin.com"];
NSData *dataFromUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSDictionary* Data = [object objectForKey:@"Data"];
```

but I can't get to "temp_C" because I don't know how to get data like \"data\": 
or \"temp_C\":\"29\"

In this case,I want to get the value of \"temp_C"\ that is 29.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Log `object` and add the result to the question

Comment: I guess that there is some wrong encoding involved at the sender's side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow that is messed up. You have JSON with a single key and value.

The key is `Data` the value is a string: `{ "data": { "current_condition": [ {"cloudcover": "0", "humidity": "33", "observation_time": "07:40 AM", "precipMM": "0.0", "pressure": "1008", "temp_C": "29", "temp_F": "84", "visibility": "10" } ] }}`.

So the value is a string that contains an inner JSON object.

You need to double deserialize this.

```
NSDictionary *JSON1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options: kNilOptions error:&err];
NSData *dataForData = [JSON1[@"Data"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *JSON2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataForData options: kNilOptions error:&err];

NSArray *celciusTemperatures = [JSON2 valueForKeyPath:@"data.current_condition.temp_C"];
NSString *firstCelciusTemperature = [celciusTemperatures firstObject];
```

Comment: If this is a publicly available server, please tell us which one so it can be avoided. If this is some in-house server, tell your boss to hire some server devs who can produce proper JSON code.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `[object objectForKey:@"Data"]` is not a *dictionary* but a *string*
containing a JSON object for a dictionary. Therefore the following should work:

```
NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSString* tmpString = [object objectForKey:@"Data"];
NSData *tmpData = [tmpString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tmpData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
```

Now `data` is a dictionary and you can access its contents, for example

```
NSDictionary *currentCondition = data[@"data"][@"current_condition"][0];
NSString *tempC = currentCondition[@"temp_C"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why, but what you have there is JSON defining a single object with a single property, `Data`, which has a string value. That string contains JSON. E.g., you have JSON wrapped in JSON.

The best answer is probably to fix the source so it doesn't return this odd nested structure.

However, to get at `temp_C`, first you decode the outer layer and get the string from `Data`. Then you decode *that* string to get the actual information, which looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "current_condition": [
            {
                "cloudcover": "0",
                "humidity": "33",
                "observation_time": "07:40 AM",
                "precipMM": "0.0",
                "pressure": "1008",
                "temp_C": "29",
                "temp_F": "84",
                "visibility": "10"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From the resulting object, get the `data` property value (an object), then get that object's `current_condition` property (an array), get its first entry (an object), and get the `temp_C` value from that object.